# How can I manage the Slick-Nav? Slick-Nav creating the problem when i include Php code in the section

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bootstrap-4

**How can I manage the Slick-Nav in my code? Slick-Nav creating the problem when i include PHP code in the section. I want to separate the slick-nav according to the section. All the navs are jumpled-up with each other as you can see in this image:

[image]

My code:

```
<?php
include("Admin/includes/db.php");

$query = "SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3;";
$run = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run)) {
    $ProId          = $row['id'];
    $ProTitle       = $row['title'];
    $ProPrice       = $row['price'];
    $ProImage       = $row['img'];
    $Category       = $row['category'];
?>
<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
  <div class="section-title">
    <h4 class="title">Top selling</h4>
    <div class="section-nav">
      <div id="slick-nav-3" class="products-slick-nav"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="products-widget-slick" data-nav="#slick-nav-3">
    <div>
      <div class="product-widget">
        <div class="product-img">
          <img src="./img/product07.png" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="product-body">
          <p class="product-category">Category</p>
          <h3 class="product-name"><a href="#">product name goes here</a></h3>
          <h4 class="product-price">
            $980.00 <del class="product-old-price">$990.00</del>
          </h4>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="product-widget">
        <div class="product-img">
          <img src="./img/product08.png" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="product-body">
          <p class="product-category">Category</p>
          <h3 class="product-name"><a href="#">product name goes here</a></h3>
          <h4 class="product-price">
            $980.00 <del class="product-old-price">$990.00</del>
          </h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="product-widget">
        <div class="product-img">
          <img src="./img/product09.png" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="product-body">
          <p class="product-category">Category</p>
          <h3 class="product-name"><a href="#">product name goes here</a></h3>
          <h4 class="product-price">
            $980.00 <del class="product-old-price">$990.00</del>
          </h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- product widget -->
    </div>

    <div>
      <!-- product widget -->
      <div class="product-widget">
        <div class="product-img">
          <img src="./img/product01.png" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="product-body">
          <p class="product-category">Category</p>
          <h3 class="product-name"><a href="#">product name goes here</a></h3>
          <h4 class="product-price">
            $980.00 <del class="product-old-price">$990.00</del>
          </h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="product-widget">
        <div class="product-img">
          <img src="./img/product02.png" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="product-body">
          <p class="product-category">Category</p>
          <h3 class="product-name"><a href="#">product name goes here</a></h3>
          <h4 class="product-price">
            $980.00 <del class="product-old-price">$990.00</del>
          </h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="product-widget">
        <div class="product-img">
          <img src="./img/product03.png" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="product-body">
          <p class="product-category">Category</p>
          <h3 class="product-name"><a href="#">product name goes here</a></h3>
          <h4 class="product-price">
            $980.00 <del class="product-old-price">$990.00</del>
          </h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the beginning of your php code, but probably you put all slick-nav code inside a loop. Parent  `<div class="products-widget-slick" data-nav="#slick-nav-3">` should be outside the loop.

Comment: <?php
              include("Admin/includes/db.php");
                  $query = "SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5;";
                  $run = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
                  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run)) {
                          $ProId          = $row['id'];
                          $Category       = $row['category'];
                ?>

Comment: Yes, `while` is a loop. So it's repeating `<div class="products-widget-slick" data-nav="#slick-nav-3">....</div>` container for every product. That's why you get extra arrows. You should place parent div element outside of the loop.

Comment: Issue is still occure :(

Comment: Edit your question with your modified code (including php part), so I'll be able to check what's wrong

Comment: Yes, all the html code is still inside the loop. Move `<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
  <div class="section-title">
    <h4 class="title">Top selling</h4>
    <div class="section-nav">
      <div id="slick-nav-3" class="products-slick-nav"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="products-widget-slick" data-nav="#slick-nav-3">` before starting `<?php` tag and move `</div>` after `<?php } ?>`.